# USB cable for power delivery max voltage

Tags: voltage, power, current

I have a USB cable with the following markings on it

`AWM 80°C 30V VW-1 28AWGX1P 24AWGX2C`

Inside the cable there are 4 wires. I would like to use the VCC and GND wire as power lines, (not using the USB connectors, and was wondering what the max voltage / current would be for those wires.

[image]

Do these markings mean that up to 30V can be applied to the VCC (red wire) and GND (green wire) inside this cable ? And is there any indication on the amount of current that can pass through such a wire ? (The application will consume around 50mA, with perhaps some very small peaks upwards to 200mA).

Answer (score 2):

The 30V means the cable is rated for 30V max, so, yes, you can apply max 30V to the cable.

When checking the very conservative [AWG chart](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm), column "Maximum amps for 
power transmission", the 28 AWG wires can carry 226 mA for those circumstances. So, in your case, either 24 AWG or 28 AWG can easily carry 50 mA.

Small current **peaks** are not interesting, because the current rating is based heating up the cables, and peaks will hardly contribute.